# Python Text Extraction Tesseract

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I am trying to extract text from an image using python tesseract. I have tried multiple fail extractions. What is the reason that tesseract is unable to extract text?
Here is the image [[image]]

**Code**

```
import cv2
import pytesseract as pt
inp = "./image.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(inp)
print(pt.image_to_string(img))
```

**Version**

```
tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1
 leptonica-1.75.3
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.2) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0

 Found AVX512BW
 Found AVX512F
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found SSE
```

Comment: And .. the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do some preprocessing with opencv to fix the problem

```py
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract # pip install pytesseract
import cv2 # pip install opencv-python

# Opens the image with opencv
image = cv2.imread("test.jpg",0) #change to your file
# Preprocesses the image
thresh = cv2.threshold(image,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Only prints allowed chars which is 0123456789:
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng', \
           config='--psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789:'))
```

Output:

```
05:26:34
09:04:24
01:00:31
01:14:36
01:17:43
02:31:05
02:35:41
05:32:42
03:26:09
02:44:11
02:56:00
02:32:42
02:35:16
07:16:10
07:18:36
07:19:00
07:19:32
07:21:17
07:21:48
```

Keep in mind you also need tesseract installed and added to the path

If you get a lot of random stuff or it didn't find the language "eng" there is a easy fix:
`If you are on linux cd into /usr/local/share/tessdata or /usr/share/tessdata and run`

```
sudo wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/master/eng.traineddata
```

That will download the english language file and hopefully fix the problem

Tessreact version:

```
>> tesseract --version
tesseract 4.1.1
 leptonica-1.81.0
  libgif 5.2.1 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 2.1.0) : libpng 1.6.37 : libtiff 4.3.0 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 1.2.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE
 Found libarchive 3.5.1 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.5 bz2lib/1.0.8 liblz4/1.9.3 libzstd/1.4.5
```

Comment: Hi @Realglass I tried your code and the output is coming different for me. Output : DESPA TELS
Centers)
CrRt EES
(rRSE EET
(reerare]
02:31:05
(Peeree an
05:32:42
Perce)
(Peer Eee
Pee)
(PaErae rd
(PeeSeer
07:16:10
raSereT]
CraSeEe)
07:19:32
Crarseeed
ase Gt

Comment: Are you sure you got the english language working correctly? If you are on linux cd into /usr/local/share/tessdata or /usr/share/tessdata and run `sudo wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/master/eng.traineddata`
That will download the english language file and maybe fix the problem

Comment: Hi I replace eng.traineddata file from '/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata' and result are improved but still not same as you got Output: LIFPLEY
09:04:24
01:00:31
01:14:36
01:17:43
02:31:05
02:35:41
05:32:42
03:26:09
02:44:11
LRI
02:32:42
IR
07:16:10
LIy
LIaERe
07:19:32
LIgrststd
07:21:48

Comment: Hi, I have included the version in question. This can help

Comment: You are using another version than I am. I included my versioning in my answer

Comment: Hi Realglass. I tried without thresholding and it is extracting perfectly. thank you for suggesting updating the eng-data file. Can you please put that comment in the answer so I can mask it answered.

Comment: I updated my answer. What linux distro are you using?

Comment: Linux intelserver 5.4.0-1040-azure #42~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 8 19:05:32 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I don't use a debian based distro myself but this should work `sudo apt update && sudo apt install tesseract-ocr`